# C++ reading from file - last element gets read twice

Tags: c++, file-io, stl, eof

I'm trying to read a file containing several variable length lists. Each list is on one line and I read it into a vector. But the last element on each line is getting stored into the vector twice.

I've coded it along the following lines:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("myfile.txt", ifstream::in);
string line;
while(!file.eof())
{
        getline(file, line);
        stringstream buffer(line);
        vector<int> temp;
        while (!buffer.eof())
        {
                buffer >> num;
                temp.push_back(num);
        }
        for(vector<int>::iterator i = temp.begin(); i != temp.end(); ++i)
                cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

Lines of input consist of tab separated integers. There is also a tab after the last element of each line.
For a line like

```
1    3    4    2
```

The expected output is

```
1 3 4 2
```

The output I'm getting is

```
1 3 4 2 2
```

Comment: Where do people get taught `while (!file.eof())`? Genuine question.

Comment: The internet, I guess. Is it wrong? What do you recommend instead?

Comment: Google the very title of your question...

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: By the way instead of looping to add elements to the vector you may want to do : `std::vector<int> temp(std::istream_iterator<int>(buffer), {});`

Comment: @juanchopanza: It's the bad design of the I/O Streams library. And it shows you have important good naming is. `eof()` misleadingly reads as "is stream at end?", there's no denying in that. A longer and complicated name would be in order, something like `operation_encountered_eof()`. Unfortunately, we are left with the horrible naming and its consequences.